# DataSource.Error: SharePoint: Request failed

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerbi, powerquery

I am using Power BI Desktop and trying to query data from a Excel files stored on a SharePoint Online list.

```
let
    Fonte = SharePoint.Files("https://eletromarquez.sharepoint.com/sites/EDPAutomaoeTelecom",[ApiVersion = 15]),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(Fonte, each Text.StartsWith([Folder Path], "https://eletromarquez.sharepoint.com/sites/EDPAutomaoeTelecom/Documentos Partilhados/Produtividade")),
    #"Linhas Filtradas1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Linhas Filtradas", each ([Extension] = ".xlsx"))
in
    #"Linhas Filtradas1"
```

I get this intermitent error:

```
DataSource.Error: SharePoint: Request failed: https://eletromarquez.sharepoint.com/sites/EDPAutomaoeTelecom/Documentos Partilhados/Produtividade/8 - Agosto 2020/Produtividade Agosto 2020 - NAME OF FILE_xlsx/_api/contextinfo
Details:
    DataSourceKind=SharePoint
    DataSourcePath=https://eletromarquez.sharepoint.com/sites/EDPAutomaoeTelecom
    SPRequestGuid=97d2889f-40d6-0000-68ed-304cacb0d4d7
```

Intermitente because sometimes the query works and sometimes don't, besides that the file pointed at error message changes at each error.

Looking for solutions in this forum, I saw that some people had the same issue but with no definitive solution.
Example: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Power-Query/DataSource-Error-SharePoint-Request-failed/td-p/210387

Previous suggestions I've tried and didn't work:

- Update Excel and Power BI (I tried to query in both applications)
- Clear permissions and log in again.

Sorry my bad English,

Best Regards,

Eduardo Donato

Answer (score 1):

I found that turning off the parallel data loading (i.e., uncheck box) in the options for data load enabled me to get past this same issue.

Comment: I could not find this option at Excel's Power Query options. I think this is only available at Power BI (where I found it).

your suggestion makes sense, because when I update each query manually, it works. But when I update via the "Refresh All" button, the error happens.

Reference: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Desktop-automatic-refresh-queries-one-by-one/td-p/155889/page/2